# iOS Unit testing UIViewControllers

Tags: unit-testing, ios

Almost all my unit tests contains the following

```
- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    self.viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    [self.viewController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

I think it makes my tests pretty slow. Is this a common practice? How should I test my ViewControllers in the best possible way?

Answer (score -1):

This is absolutely fine as in Apple sample documentation they also use the above logic to get reference to the objects for tests.

See below image it is from sample Apple code
[image]